# WordPress Return array with post ID's based on meta_value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to figure out something that should be fairly easy I think. I have custom fields named 'include-in-nav'. I'm using wp_nav_menu() to create a menu:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(     'theme_location' => 'primary', 
                        'menu_id' => 'primary-menu',
                        'include' => $post_ids

                ) 
        );
```

I've tried to get an array with post id's based on wether 'include-in-nav' is true or not. I've tried get_posts() and WP_query() but whatever i'm trying, nothing seems to return an array with post ID's. Any suggestions?

-edit my attempt to get $post_ids:

```
$post_ids = get_posts(array(
        'post'
        'meta_value'    => 'include-in-main-nav'
));
```

and

```
$nav_posts = array(
        'meta_value'    => 'include-in-main-nav'
));

$wp_query = new WP_Query($nav_posts);

$post_ids = array();

while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
   $post_ids[] = get_the_ID() ;
endwhile;
```

Comment: Can you update your post with code of your attempts to get the posts via get_posts() and WP_query() please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well other than a flat our sql query, nope.

you can use the wp_query with a meta query nested in. this will return posts though. you will need to loop through the posts as you would normally

example of a query like the one you need:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'  => 'page',
'meta_key'   => 'include-in-main-nav',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'include-in-main-nav',
        'value'   => 1,
        'compare' => '=',
    ),
),
);
 $query = new WP_Query( $args );


if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>    
        <!-- MOO! time to display your menu items! -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

note: from there you can also fill an array with your ids.. if you really  really need an array with only your ids in it.

Have fun! hope this helps you out m8!

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. Used this to indeed still create an array with ID's so that I can use wp_nav_menu function.